# How to install package with yum without updating repository information?

Tags: yum, installation, repository, packages

I want to install some packages from repository but always when I'm trying to `yum install packagename` yum updates db:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Determining fastest mirrors
updates/metalink                                                                                                                      |  23 kB     00:00     
 * fedora: nl.mirror.eurid.eu
 * rpmfusion-free: ftp.astral.ro
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: ftp.astral.ro
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: ftp.astral.ro
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: ftp.astral.ro
 * updates: nl.mirror.eurid.eu
fedora-awesome                                                                                                                    | 3.3 kB     00:00     
google-chrome                                                                                                                     |  951 B     00:00     
rpmfusion-free-updates                                                                                                        | 3.3 kB     00:00     
rpmfusion-free-updates/primary_db                                                                                             | 272 kB     00:08     
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates                                                                                                     | 3.3 kB     00:00     
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates/primary_db                                                                                          |  93 kB     00:05     
updates                                                                                                                       | 4.7 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                                                                                            | 4.6 MB     02:35     
updates/group                                                                                                                     | 1.9 MB     00:33
```

So using `yum install packagename -C` also not works ("cache not found" error happens and `yum makecache` don't give results too).
But I just want to install packages without updating db.

Comment: Why? Updating the DB means you have the latest versions of the package list

Comment: What db are we talking about? The yum repo/package cache?

Comment: @sam because my Internet speed is too slow to update repo for every installation.

Comment: @thinice yes as you see in log there is update happens for ever repository. I don't need it to do I just want to install package without repository updating.

Comment: @purple Then you should be using a local repository, yum is designed to work with full access to the repo data, be it remote or local yum doesn't care but it should have it.

Comment: Use `-C` option.

See questions [Disable YUM mirrorlist checking](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137569/disable-yum-mirrorlist-checking) and [Yum – disable database update on package install](http://superuser.com/questions/317417/yum-disable-database-update-on-package-install).

Answer (score 13):

If you want `yum` to behave like `apt-get` (not to update the metadata by each run), edit `/etc/yum.conf` and put there:

`metadata_expire=never`

or

`metadata_expire=7d`

in case you want to update the metadata after a week. If you run `yum makecache`, your metadata will be updated like by `apt-get update` in Debian.

But keep in mind that if you use "never" in the config file, you will have to care about that manually. If you use i.e. "7d", you will save your data bandwidth, but after a week, the metadata will be updated for you automatically.

Here is the `metadata_expire` documentation:

> You can also change from the default of using seconds to  using days,  hours  or  minutes  by appending a d, h or m respectively.  The default is 6 hours, to compliment yum-updatesd running once an hour.  It's also possible to use the word "never", meaning that the metadata will never expire.

Comment: will `2w` work as well?

Comment: No `2w` doesn't work. The default is 6 hours, to compliment yum-updatesd running once an hour. You can change from the default of using seconds to  using days,  hours  or  minutes  by appending `a d, h or m` respectively.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to install a package without updating the db, you download the rpm directly (either via yumdownloader, ftp or web browser) and then install it with the rpm directly:

```
rpm -ivh packagename
```

I do not recommend you do this, as it is a lot more work to track down the dependencies (that is why yum is created) and it could break future installs via yum.

Comment: Yes but why apt-get for example doesn't update repository when you just tell him to install package? And for updating you use 'apt-get update' command.

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking is out of the spirit of yum in some regards. Yum is a comprehensive package and *dependency* manager. In order to do it's job and not screw up your system by mix-and-matching incompatible packages, it needs to have that data you don't want to update.

You can manually analyze what dependencies a package has by using `deplist <packagename>` and install them manually.

Not having yum have an up-to-date seems like an odd request whatever the circumstances...

Comment: But why apt-get don't update repository when you type install command? It will update repository only and only when you type update. I want yum to do the same thing.

Comment: If you run apt-get install foo - and the remote package version has changed, you'll get messages like this: https://bitbucket.org/ianb/silverlining/issue/26/run-apt-get-update-before-apt-get-install -  Likewise with any dependencies that have been updated in the repo as well. (Essentially, forcing you to run update).

Comment: Yes but when I run yum to install application which hasn't been changed it updates db too.